# This process will continue UP TO A TIME in the future

Tags: word-choice, grammar

When I am about to tell you that the process is still going to continue, but unsure at what exact point of time the process will end.

Is the sentence "This process will continue up to a time in the future." acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I would find the original sentence ("This process will continue up to a time in the future") ambiguous.  That's because it doesn't specify if the ending time has been decided on or not. It leaves the reader hanging.

To make it clear that the ending time is not yet known--and that you're not just being coy by intentionally holding back information--the stock-phrase I'm used to hearing is "This process will continue up to an undetermined time in the future."

I see that fumble-fingers already mentioned this is a comment.

Comment: OP's text makes it clear the process *will* end at some point. It's definitely *not* the case that *This process will continue [**indefinitely**]* (where that last word would be implicit if not explicitly stated). If it was important to reassure the audience that there *would* be an end, you'd probably go for something more like *This process will **eventually** end*, But unless that's the whole point of the utterance, it seems only natural to give some indication of *why* the speaker can't say exactly when that end will arrive.

Comment: "This process will continue up to a time in the future" comes very close to being platitudinous.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, the progress cannot continue, because progress cannot "move" -it's the *state* of the task in question, at any given time - you could say "Progress is at 85%" for example.  The **task** or **process** can continue, and as it continues it **progresses**, or **makes progress**.

To say that it's going to end in the future is pointless as well - it's either going to go on **for ever** or it's going to end at some point, and that point will be in the future as that's just how time works.

So, if you basically wanted to say "This process is going to continue for a while, but I don't know how long", but want to dress it up a bit more nicely, you could say

> "This task may take some time to complete"

or, you could just skip over the fact that you don't actually know how long it's going to take, and just say

> "Processing..."

or something.  In cases like this it's good to show some sort of change or movement, just to tell the user (I'm assuming this is in the context of software) that it hasn't completely broken.  Often this is done by adding another "." after "Processing" every five seconds, or something like that, just so it does actually look like it is progressing (even if it has crashed in the background).